# metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases

Tags: python, django, postgresql, aggregate, partition

I am trying to implement multiple inheritance with Partitioned model and Aggregate Model

`class AdAgencyLocationPurposeAggregate(PostgresAggregateModel,PostgresPartitionedModel):`

`PostgresAggregateModel`:

`class PostgresAggregateModel(PostgresModel,metaclass=PostgresAggregateModelMeta ):`

`PostgresPartitionedModel`

`class PostgresPartitionedModel( PostgresModel,metaclass=PostgresPartitionedModelMeta ):`

Comment: You can't inherit from two different metaclasses.

Comment: @snakecharmerb what will be the possible solution then to inherit from two different classes?